# How to Decompress the file in C

Tags: c, compression

I have this code written in C i want to decompress it but i am not able to do so .

Please help me in this regard . I want to decompress a text file which I have in the folder
. I am lost here in the decompression method don't know how to do so

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char find[100000];

char* StrCompress(char myStr[]);

int go()
{
    FILE* custom = NULL;
    custom = fopen("newfile.txt", "r");
    if(custom == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n Unable to open file testing.txt");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE* future = NULL;
    future = fopen("new.txt", "w");
    if(future== NULL)
    {
        printf("\n Unable to open file new.txt");
        return 1;
    }

     while(fscanf(custom, "%s", find)!=EOF)
     {
     //Use data read in find here
        printf("%s", StrCompress(find));
        fprintf(future, "%s ", StrCompress(find));
     }

fclose(custom);
fclose(future);
}

char* StrCompress(char myStr[])
{
    char *s = myStr;
    char *r, *p;
    int count, i;

    while (*s)
    {
        count = 1;

        while (*s == *(s+1) && *s)
        {
            count++;
            s++;
        }

        if (count > 1)
        {
            *(s - count + 2) = count + '0';

            for (i = 0; i < count - 2; i++)
            {
                p = s + 1;
                r = s;

                while (*r)
                    *r++ = *p++;
                                    s--;
            }
        }
        s++;
    }

    return myStr;
}

int main()
{
    go();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about "Please write my code for me.".

Comment: How is the file compressed? What have you tried?

Comment: Yes it is compress i used the RLE method to compress the file

Comment: Please submit correctly formatted code.

Answer (score 1):

From wikipedia :
WWWWWWWWWWWWBWWWWWWWWWWWWBBBWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWBWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
If we apply the run-length encoding (RLE) data compression algorithm to the above hypothetical scan line, we get the following:
12W1B12W3B24W1B14W

So if your compression is right (haven't checked but your question is about decompression), getting back the original string is pretty straightforward.

- read the stream char by char
- get the int, which is the number of time the char will be used
- get the corresponding char
- print it
- carry on